# How to make d3 title on a chart responsive?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this code snippet that adds title to a chart, how can I make it responsive?

```
        d3.select('#chart svg').append('text')
        .attr('x', d3.select('#chart svg').node().getBoundingClientRect().width / 2)
        .attr('y',20)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .style('font-size', '1.4em')
        .style('fill','white')
        .text(item1.chart_title);
```

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1bxe2scd/1/

Comment: Responsive to what? Based on the fiddle, this seems like more of a c3 question than a d3 question. I don't know c3, but the on.click in the fiddle appears to be broken. Do you want the title to reflect the bar that was clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a class and have that class behave differently for different screen sizes using media queries:

```
.attr('class', 'resp-font')

.resp-font {
    //media query for small
    font-size: 12px;

    //media query for large
    font-size: 18px;
}
```